# How do I transfer a strong id variable into a UIImage variable?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

I have a variable

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id dataObject;
```

It is a pointer to a `UIImage`.  I want to send it to my new variable.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *theImage;
```

When I try to do this, the app crashes with this error:
`unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68423b0`

How do I send it to my new variable?  Thanks in advance.

contentViewController.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "pageAppViewController.h"

@class pageAppViewController;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{
    NSArray *content;
    UIImageView *theImageView;
    UIImage *theImage;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *theImageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id dataObject;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *theImage;

@end
```

contentViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "pageAppViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize theImageView, dataObject;
@synthesize theImage;


- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //this is the line that is causing the problems.
    theImage = dataObject;
    theImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: theImage];

    [self.view addSubview:theImageView];   
}
@end
```

Comment: try this
theImage =(UIImage*) dataObject;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just set it to UIImage instead of id in your interface, Why the (id)?

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *dataObject;
```

Are the Images of type NSData?

Comment: I just tried that and it still did not work. dataObject is derived from the following code.  It is an objectAtIndex from an array of UIImages called book.                                              - (ViewController *) viewControllerAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index
{
    ViewController *dataViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController"  bundle:nil];
    
    dataViewController.dataObject = [self.book objectAtIndex:index];
    
    return dataViewController;
}

Answer (score 0):

When you have a property defined as an `id` it tells the compiler that it can be any kind of object. If you now want to assign this object to a known type and you are sure that the object behind `id` is of the same type you can just cast it.

**Example**

```
id someObject = [UIImage imageNamed:@"x.png"];

UIImage *myImage = (UIImage*) someObject;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I still have one problem  someObject is a pointer to an image that is taken from an array of images and changes as the user changes images.  So I can't set it to one image.  Is there another way to set id someObject to a UIImage?

Comment: I'm not sure if you know this, but UIImage can't be saved to an NSArray. You need to save it as NSData. UIImage has a method: imageWithData: that you can use to get an image from an NSData object.

Comment: @HubertKunnemeyer that is not true. You may add UIImages to an NSArray and retrieve them later without any problem. What makes you think that storing a UIImage within an NSArray would be invalid?